# Bootstrap 3 dropdown does not allow scrolling on Windows Phone 8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8

I have a dropdown using the default bootstrap 3 markup:

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
     Menu
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choice..</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

As I want to limit the size of the dropdown so it doesn't expand all the way down the page I added this CSS rule:

```
.dropdown-menu{
   max-height: 220px; 
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This works fine in all browsers but when I try to open the dropdown on WP8 the dropdown is not scrollable and I can't get to any of the values that are cut off. Emulating this in IE with WP8 settings works but on the actual device it doesn't. Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Live version here: [Bootply live demo](http://www.bootply.com/121754)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `-ms-overflow-style` property. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
.dropdown-menu { 
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alain, That does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Strange, can you try setting overflow:scroll; instead of overflow-y:scroll; ?

Comment: Also, attempt to set a height property additional to the max-height one. Sorry I can't see the problem from here but I'll still attempt to help you

Comment: Hi Alain, I appreciate your help. I tried both but the dropdown still does not allow me to scroll.